# VerticaCopyStream is very slow

Tags: java, json, jdbc, vertica

I use vertica flex table to load json to vertica without defining the tables, and I got problems with my loading time.

I connect to my vertica with jdbc drive and then use this code..

```
String copyQuery = "COPY schema.tablename FROM STDIN PARSER fjsonparser()";
VerticaCopyStream vstream = new VerticaCopyStream((VerticaConnection)conn, copyQuery);
InputStream input;
vstream.start();
for(JsonNode json : jsonList){
     input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes());
     vstream.addStream(input);
     input.close();
}
vstream.execute();
vstream.finish();
```

The command "vstream.execute()" takes 12 seconds for 5000 jsons but when I use COPY command from file it runs for less then a second.

Comment: In the case of the COPY command that run fast . did you run it from the vertica sever ?

Comment: no, i run it from my local computer. when i run COPY comand from the server with a text file, it run at less then then 1 sec

Comment: Just to clarify . your copy command test is with csv file and the VerticaCopyStream is with json or both are json ?

Comment: yes, my copy comand is with csv file and the java copy is json

Comment: Did you disable autocommit?

Comment: yes, after i ask the commpany about it the best way to load is by using COPY command from vsql

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the VerticaCopyStream , the problem is with regard to the different parsers you used , you need to compare apple to apple , JSON parser should be more slower the simple CSV parser .

Comment: it to slow to be true! =(

Comment: No sure about your comment , just compare you input json file length with the CSV , think about the network overhead and the extra parsing and it should make seems

Answer (score 1):

`COPY FROM STDIN` and `COPY LOCAL` stream data from the client. Running it on the server with just a `COPY` (no LOCAL or STDIN) will be a direct load straight from the vertica daemon with no network latency (assuming it is on local disk and not a NAS).

In addition, your method of reinstantiating the ByteArrayInputStream... wouldn't it be better to turn your jsonList into an InputStream and pass just that in instead of creating an input stream for every item?

Answer (score 0):

if you run the samr insert by useing vsql it solve the problem